# Object is not displaying on the ground plane even if it is set to true in vuforia ground plane detection

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia

i have used vuforia and i am trying to display only one object at a time on ground plane when i use play the log says the object's active state is true but when i run it on my phone it doesn't show. 
my main cs script is in camera.
[image: my cs script is on camera]
public class data : MonoBehaviour
{

```
public GameObject[] items;
// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{

    items[0].SetActive(false);
    items[1].SetActive(false);
    items[2].SetActive(false);
    items[3].SetActive(false);

    for (int i=0;i<items.Length;i++)
    {
        Debug.Log(items[i].name);
        if (items[i].name== "kids_wooden_desk")
        {
            items[i].SetActive(true);
        }
        Debug.Log(items[i].activeSelf);
    }

    //g.SetActive(true);
    }
private void OnDestroy()
{

}
// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{

}
```

}

Comment: Does it work in the Editor? If so check logcat to see if there is any exception in your code.

Comment: Have you set up the Ground plane and object placement correctly?